# User friendly software for math drawings

Tags: math-software

I am a math grad student and these days I am writing my thesis using $\LaTeX$. I have to use few 2D graphs that contain curves and shaded regions with few labeling. Can anybody please recommend me a user friendly free software that I can use to draw my figures?

Comment: It shouldn't be hard with `pstricks` or `tikz-pgf`. You'll have a better integration to your document than with an external software.

Comment: I always used Mathematica with the Save As... functionality. Save to pdf, then include the pdf in your document.

Comment: Geogebra has an intuitive GUI and it can export to tikz.

Comment: Another vote for *Mathematica*, which I have used exclusively for several books, including the book I'm writing now.

Comment: along with the other recommendations, take a quick look at draw.io, might be of some help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’d look into Tikz, which is a package for LaTeX. It’s fairly intuitive if you’ve used LaTeX before and I think (based on your description) it’s good for what you’re going for.

[Here’s](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/LaTeX_Graphics_using_TikZ:_A_Tutorial_for_Beginners_(Part_1)%E2%80%94Basic_Drawing) a link to an Overleaf page describing some of its basic functionality:

There’s obviously more you can do with it (I recently used it/an extension of it to draw circuits for a Laplace transform paper I wrote), so you can do some more googling to find what you think you need out of it. Good luck!

Comment: +1 with modifications. I find tikz very useful but with a steep learning curve. So what I do is find some code that does as much as possible of what I want, try to modify it (cargo cult programming, I'm afraid), then ask politely at tex stackexchange for help.  I always get it.

Comment: @EthanBolker: from my point of view, `pstricks` has the advantage to use LaTeX syntax, so the learning curve is not so steep. Furthermore, it is well documented, with many examples, and the documentation has a sensible size.

Answer (score 0):

Tikz is a great choice, but not very user-friendly (i suppose same goes for asymptote).

I would recommend [Geogebra](https://www.geogebra.org/classic) if you want something more user friendly or WYSIWYG type. Besides, one could draw in geogebra and then export it to tikz/pstricks.

One big advantage of tikz over graphic softwares is `styles`. But, one can draw in geogebra, export it to tikz, and then incorporate tikz styles (by editing tikz code). There are other things in tikz one cannot hope to achieve in a drawing software (eg: markings on line/curve in tikz).